# Preview issue in UIKit (after adding multiple environment to handle google-service.plist)

Tags: swiftui, uikit

Cannot preview in this file - not buidling -Onone

HumanReadableSwiftError

CreationError: noBuildExecutor

OptimizationLevelError: not building -Onone

"NameOfApp Development.app" needs -Onone Swift optimization level to use previews

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I fix the error I need to change SWIFT_OPTIMZATION_LEVEL from build settings for debug from target and pods to be  -NoOne

Answer (score 1):

please sure sure that you have not changed anything in scheme.

go to **Product > Scheme > Edit scheme**

Make sure sure that the build configuration is set to staging 'debug' as opposed to being 'release'

[Edit scheme screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VLzV.png)

Comment: If you like you can move the part I deleted into a comment, it is however not part of an answer. Compare [answer].